# Yarn: add dependency from subdirectory in git repository

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

I use yarn in my React Native project. I would like to add [a fork of jest-enzyme](https://github.com/lifeiscontent/enzyme-matchers) package to my dependencies (the fork adds Flow type definitions).

The problem is that the package I need is not in the root of repository but in `packages/jest-enzyme` subdirectory.

Running `yarn add --dev https://github.com/lifeiscontent/enzyme-matchers.git` installs the whole `enzyme-assertions` package.

If I try to import it as `import 'enzyme-assertions/jest-enzyme';`, I get "Cannot find module" error. `import 'jest-enzyme';` does not work either (same error).

I also tried running `yarn add --dev https://github.com/lifeiscontent/enzyme-matchers.git/packages/jest-enzyme`, but this is not supported (I am getting 404 error). `#` is for branches, commits and tags, so I don't think it will work.

**So how do I install this package?**

Answer (score 2):

Try https://gitpkg.now.sh/

```sh
yarn add https://gitpkg.now.sh/<user>/<repo>/<subdir>[?<branch>]
```

For this question:

```sh
yarn add https://gitpkg.now.sh/enzyme-matchers/packages/jest-enzyme
```

Comment: This does not work with yarn 3.

Comment: does this work with Private/Organization github repositories?

Comment: This works for me, if you see 500 internal server error, try to add ?<branch>

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to directly reference the submodule path?

```
import jestEnzyme from 'enzyme-matchers/packages/jest-enzyme';
```

Note that the project is a multirepository managed by [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna), so the sub-packages provide only the source code, which still needs to be builded/compiled in order to be used.